# Sonatype Nexus: YUM Generate Metadata: repomd.xml unavailable during rebuild

Tags: nexus, yum

We have a Scheduled Task "YUM: Generate Metadata" with Full Rebuild
checked.  What we are observing (using wget of the repomd.xml) is the
repomd.xml requests are influnced by the rebuild.  What normally takes
1 second, can take the duration of the rebuild (2.5 minutes in my
case) to fetch.

Is this expected behavior?  Shouldn't the current one be made available until the rebuild is complete?

We are running Nexus 2.11.4-01.

(We tried to go without the full rebuild, but the Tasks get increasing
in duration, more than 45 minutes, and eventually just failed.  So we
don't want to go down that path again.)

TIA!
LennyB

Comment: In terms of expected behavior you'll have to ask someone from Nexus I imagine. Unless someone here is intimately familiar with it and sees this.